# Jquery: resize iframe based on window-resize and keep last shown content

Tags: jquery

Another jquery-problem.........

I succeeded in resizing a page based on windows.height and windows.width. This page contains a div and an iframe. If that page is resized the iframe is always showing the default content and not the content that was visible before the window was resized.

How can I keep the last shown content of the iframe when resizing the window??

---

[EDIT]

I think I need to be more specific (my fault)........

The page (index.php) consists of a DIV containing just URLs. When visiting an URL the result is shown in an iframe. The iframe has a fixed width of 100% and the height depends on the height of the browser window (pixels) minus 100.

```
$('#frame').attr('width',$(window).width());
$('#frame').attr('height',($(window).height() - 100));
```

I also use variables to pass in the main URL: index.php?sw=....&sh=.....
These variables (sw=screenwidth and sh=screenheight) are being used in other subpages.

If my page is called in the browser, like "/" ....... a redirect is made to /index.php?sw=....&sh=.. (because I need these variables sw/sh in subpages):

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                <?php if (empty($_GET['sh'])){ ?>
                $(window).height(); // Height
                $(window).width(); //  Width
                window.location.href="index.php?sw=" + $(window).width() + "&sh=" + $(window).height();
            <?php } ?>
```

If I resize the browser window the "window.location.href" is renewed with updated values for sw and sh.

```
                $(window).resize(function() {                  
                    window.location.href="index.php?sw=" + $(window).width() + "&sh=" + $(window).height();
            });
```

Resizing also means that the iframe shows the default content. How can I pass the last shown iframe-content (the fact that the URL is from a cross domain or my own domain should not matte because my iframe-width is fixed and the height = window.height-100.)

Comment: is the iframe's content of your domain or is it crossdomain?

Comment: The content of the iframe is on my domain!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

To keep the content I have 2 ideas:

(1) when updating the location add 1 additional GET parameter storing the Iframes content URL

(2) instead of reloading the page try updating your parameters of the URL. You can do this by changing from standard GET parameters to custom parameters by adding the `#` after your `index.php`.
    Example:

```
index.php#sw=" + $(window).width() + "&sh=" + $(window).height();
  // instead of 
index.php?sw=" + $(window).width() + "&sh=" + $(window).height();
```

This can be done by setting only `window.location.hash`, which will not force the browser to reload the page, but you will if to detect the hash change everywhere where you need this parameters. Therefore I would use a custom event and trigger it inside your `$(window).resize(function() { });`.

**Original answer:**

I had a simmilar issue some month ago, which I solved with something like follows.

in HTML there was somewhere the iframe:

```
<html> 
  ...
  <body>
    ...
    <div id="main">
      ...
      <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

and in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      // do it after dom ready 
    resizeIframe();  
      // and/or retry it on load
    $('iframe#frame').load(function(){ resizeIframe(); });
      // some browsers need a little more time
    UI.setTimeout(function(){
            // and/or retry it on load
         $('iframe#frame').load(function(){ resizeIframe(); });   
    }, 100);

});

function resizeIframe(){
      // set iframe width to a little less than surrounding page's width 
    $('iframe#frame').width($('div#main').width()-50);  
      // set iframe height to iframe's content height
    $('iframe#frame').height($('iframe#frame').contents().height());
}
```

I think it should be adaptable for your needs.

Comment: I have edited my question because I was not specific enough (my fault)........sorry. Hope you can/will still help me out!!

Comment: Hi, i'm still not sure if I got your point, but I edited my answer. I'm not sure what you need  the URL parameters for and why you need the hard redirect. Normally you should use ajax requests to update the contents only where it is necessary. And modifing the dimensions of your page's elements normally is a JS only job.

Comment: Been away for a few days........I am now trying to get rid of those GET parameters containing height and width by using AJAX and POST. Will let you know how I proceed! Thx for supporting me!